# How to write a H1 over an image?

Tags: css

I need to write a text in an heading tag over an image, I get a strange problem, take a look ad the image above.

[image]

The css code is:

```
#header h1 {
    position: absolute; 
    height:19px;       
    top:105px;
    /*background-color:#OC3183;*/
    background-color:green;     
    z-index: 10000;             
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, san-serif;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 26px;
    padding-left: 1px;                                             
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;            
}
```

as you cann see if i put the green i correctly obscure the white line below, If i use the same color (navy) I see that line.... why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex-code for your navy color is wrong. it starts with the letter `O` instead of the numeral `0`.

Replace

```
background-color:#OC3183;
```

with

```
background-color:#0C3183;
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: In your code, replace `#OC3183` with `#0C3183`. See the difference with the first number after the `#`? It should be a `0` (zero) but in your example it is an `O` (the letter).

Comment: You're welcome. This one is easy to overlook, happens to me all the time. Glad I could help.

Comment: +1 Well spotted. @Dail - Your hex colour code is incorrect, just remove your 2 background-color styles, and replace with Dennis' second code

Answer (score 1):

I think these easiest way to do this is to set a background image on the h1.

```
#header h1 {
    width: 200px;
    height:19px;
    background: url(/images/background.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;
   [...]          
}
```

Comment: thank you, but is this not strange? I mean, why if i change a color I'm ABOVE the white line, and if i write the same color i'm below?